# Quicksort for Strings

Tags: algorithms, strings, quicksort

I am currently trying to study the Quicksort algorithm. I understand how it works for integers but can anyone explain how does Quicksort algorithm work with strings?

The reason for my confusion is that strings do not have values assigned to them and the Quicksort algorithm seems to be using values to arrange an array of numbers. Most of the websites I have visited do not seem to offer explanations on this and only focus more on the integer value sorts.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Depending on abstraction, Quicksort works just the same for *any* type of *keys* from an ordered domain: Pick a pivot or two, partition, solve sub-problems. `the Quicksort algorithm seems to be using values` and no surprise. Looking closer, it doesn't care about any particular value - just if one is smaller, equal to, or greater than another.

Comment: to sort with comparisons (quicksort is just one algorithm that does that), you just need an order relation in which said elements are comparable. it doesnt matter what the element is.

Answer (score 2):

The quicksort algorithm, and all other [comparison based algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), all sort the "data" (any kind of "data") if they are given a a function that can compare two data points.

In the specific case of integers - the comparison is intuitive. For strings - one might use the [alphabetical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order): for two strings $w_1,w_2$, we can say that $w_1<w_2$ if $w_1$ comes before $w_2$ lexicographically speaking.

Comment: Oh, you are saying that the algorithm makes a to have a higher value than b, making a to come before b. This makes absolute sense! Thank you